# Problema para executar arquivo .feature no PyCharm

Tags: python, bdd

Estou com problema no meu ambiente para executar arquivos `.feature`. Estou criando um Behave + Selenium e sempre que executo meu arquivo `.feature` ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
C:\Python\Python36-32\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.1\helpers\pycharm\behave_runner.py"
Testing started at 2:12 PM ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.1\helpers\pycharm\behave_runner.py", line 281, in <module>
    my_config = configuration.Configuration(command_args=command_args)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\behave\configuration.py", line 601, in __init__
    self.name_re = self.build_name_re(self.name)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\behave\configuration.py", line 665, in build_name_re
    return re.compile(pattern, flags=(re.UNICODE | re.LOCALE))
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 233, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 865, in parse
    p.pattern.flags = fix_flags(str, p.pattern.flags)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 832, in fix_flags
    raise ValueError("cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern")
ValueError: cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern
```

Porém estou conseguindo executar arquivos .py normalmente. Sei que o erro é de ambiente, porém não sei o que fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro ocorre somente quando se tenta rodar o `.feature` passando o nome de um cenário em específico com o `--name` ou `-n`. Isso por que o `re.LOCALE` foi *deprecated* a partir da versão 3.6 mas não foi removido do trecho de código do behave que seleciona o cenário por nome, como pode-se ver reportado aqui: https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/587

Se usar a versão 3.5 do Python funciona, ou se preferir conserte a lib do behave na mão removendo o `re.LOCALE`, conforme indicado nesse [bug fix](https://github.com/behave/behave/commit/f52cc2f59df8e21a5caf21b268bbd9ca6fa3e1e1), edite o arquivo `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\behave\configuration.py`

Troque a linha:

```
return re.compile(pattern, flags=(re.UNICODE | re.LOCALE))
```

por:

```
return re.compile(pattern, flags=re.UNICODE)
```